# Getting the patterns of a spacy PhraseMatcher

Tags: python, spacy

Is there any way to get a list of the patterns in a `PhraseMatcher`? For example, if I added the patterns `abc, def, efg` to a matcher, is there a way I can list out those patterns? Or even just check if `abc` is a pattern in the matcher?

Answer (score 0):

For PhraseMatcher specifically the internal list of rules is not exposed, but `__contains__` is implemented so you can do this:

```
matcher.add("abc", ...)
"abc" in matcher # => True
```

Out of curiosity what are you checking for? In my experience with the matchers usually they're just set up and used without being passed around much, I kind of have trouble imagining a situation where you'd use this feautre.